# How to change attributes of the second Activity from Main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, attributes

In the main activity I have a handler to exchange messages with the bluetooth service. This works fine.
Now, I want launch second activity (SurfaceViewAnimation). I do this with:

> startActivity (new Intent (this, SurfaceViewAnimation.class));

but I want change some attributes of SufaceViewAnimation class from main activity when it receives a command for bluetooth.

**How I can do this?**

The code of SufaceViewAnimation class is:

```
    class BouncingBallView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private BouncingBallAnimationThread bbThread = null;

    private int xPosition = getWidth()/2;
    private int yPosition = getHeight()/2;
    private int xDirection = 20;
    private int yDirection = 40;

    private static int radius = 20;
    private static int ballColor = Color.RED;

    public BouncingBallView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(ctx, attrs, defStyle);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(), paint);
            paint.setColor(ballColor);
            canvas.drawCircle(xPosition, yPosition, radius, paint);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (bbThread!=null) return;
            bbThread = new BouncingBallAnimationThread(getHolder());
            bbThread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width, int height) {  }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            bbThread.stop = true;
    }

    private class BouncingBallAnimationThread extends Thread {

            public boolean stop = false;
            private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

            public BouncingBallAnimationThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            }

            public void run() {
                    while (!stop) {
                            xPosition += xDirection;
                            yPosition += yDirection;
                            if (xPosition<0) {
                                    xDirection = -xDirection;
                                    xPosition = radius; }
                            if (xPosition>getWidth()-radius) {
                                    xDirection = -xDirection;
                                    xPosition = getWidth()-radius; }
                            if (yPosition<0) {
                                    yDirection = -yDirection;
                                    yPosition = radius; }
                            if (yPosition>getHeight()-radius) {
                                    yDirection = -yDirection;
                                    yPosition = getHeight()-radius-1; }

                            Canvas c = null;
                            try {
                                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                            onDraw(c);
                                    }
                            } finally {
                                    if (c != null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }
                    }
            }

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

       if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return false;      
       if (xDirection!=0 || yDirection!=0)      
             xDirection = yDirection = 0;       
       else {       
             xDirection = (int) event.getX() - xPosition;       
             yDirection = (int) event.getY() - yPosition;
       }    
       if(ballColor==Color.RED)
           ballColor=Color.GREEN;
       else
           ballColor=Color.RED;
       return true;     
    }

    public void setxDirection(int xDirection) {
        this.xDirection = xDirection;
    }

    public void setyDirection(int yDirection) {
        this.yDirection = yDirection;
    }

    public void setballColor(int ballColor) {
        this.ballColor = ballColor;
    }

    public void setradius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

public class SurfaceViewAnimation extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(new BouncingBallView(this,null,0));
        }
}
```

Comment: what attributes do you want to change? You can use intent.putextra().

Comment: For example, change ballColor. But, I think that only can be change this with putextra() before that activity is created or "launched" (startActivity), isn't? If I want to change the color as the activity runs I dont think this way works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data in `SurfaceViewAnimation` *while* `SurfaceViewAnimation` is running, you're best off with creating an own handler.

Besides that you can fall back to basic Inter(Process/Activity)Communication using `Handler`s, static variables or the `Observer` pattern.

Comment: You can be more specific to explain static variables or the Observer pattern? I looking for easy solution and I do not care that the solution is not the best (more efficient or "good praxis")

Comment: Im now trying to add a Handler between main activity (I get messages there) and SurfaceViewAnimation class. But, how i add the same handler if I dont call to SurfaceVoewAnimation constructor directly but through startActivity (new Intent (this, SurfaceViewAnimation.class))???